# CakePHP 3 How to use next and prev for view action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to integrate next and prev buttons in my view page for CustomersController. In my next button, I am trying to add a link that will take to next record from the table. Same for prev that will get the previous record from the table. I tried below pagination, but when I click next, it takes me to `http://localhost/path/customers/view/1?page=2` link, I want to find away that will take me to next record like this `http://localhost/path/customers/view/2`

```
// Shows the page numbers
<?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>

// Shows the next and previous links
<?= $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous') ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->next('Next »') ?>

// Prints X of Y, where X is current page and Y is number of pages
<?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?>
```

I also tried this `<?= $this->Paginator->numbers(['first' => 2, 'last' => 2]); ?>`.

Comment: ``Paginator`` Component splits a group of records in to smaller groups (pages). So for example you have 60 records in your DB. Instead of fetching all 60 records you fetch and show 15 records each time. So practically when you call function ``next()`` paginator means the next set of records (**page**) not the next record. Don't know if there is anything on CakePHP that can do what you ask. Maybe a custom PaginatorHelper of your own.

Comment: I see. Thank you gmponos. I think I have to probably make an ajax call to get the next / prev rows and update view accordingly or create a logic in view that will fatch next / prev rows and link it to buttons.

Comment: I think I got it working with cakephp `find()` method in view action. I created this code that gives me next record `$next = $this->Customers->find()->where([
                'id >' => $id
            ])->limit(1);
        $this->set('next', $next);`

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, it worked fine to me, I hope it to help you:

```
//controller view action 
public function view($id = null)
{
    $ids = Cache::read('items_ids');
    if (empty($ids)) {
        $ids = $this->Items->find('list')->toArray();
        Cache::write('items_ids', $ids);
    }
    /*
     * $ids here must be something like this:

     Array
        (
            ............
            [GS00001] => Item 1
            [GS00003] => Item 2
            ..........
        )

    */
    //pr($ids);die; //this for debug


    //seek to the item with id = $id
    while (key($ids) !== $id) next($ids);

    if($next = next($ids)){
        $next = [
            'id' => key($ids),
            'name' => current($ids)
        ];
    }else{
        end($ids);
    }

    prev($ids);
    if($prev = prev($ids)){
        $prev = [
            'id' => key($ids),
            'name' => current($ids)
        ];
    }
    //pr(compact(['next','prev']));die;
    /*

    $next and $prev here:

    If first:
    Array
    (
        [next] => false
        [prev] => Array
            (
                [id] => GS00264
                [name] => Last Item
            )

    )

    If last:
    Array
    (
        [next] => Array
            (
                [id] => GS00003
                [name] => First Item
            )

        [prev] => false
    )

     * */


    $item = $this->Items->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['MenuGroups', 'Orders']
    ]);
    $this->set(compact(['item','next','prev','ids']));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['item','next','prev','ids']);
}
```

and in the view template simply write:

```
    <ul>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link('<< ' . $prev['name'],['action'=>'view',$prev['id']]); ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link($next['name'] . ' >>',['action'=>'view',$next['id']]); ?></li>
    </ul>
```

and in **Bootstrap.css** case:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous <?= ($prev) ? '' : 'disabled' ?>">
            <?= $this->Html->link('<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> ' . $prev['name'], ['action' => 'view', $prev['id']], ['escape' => false]); ?>
        </li>
        <li class="next <?= ($next) ? '' : 'disabled' ?>">
            <?= $this->Html->link($next['name'] . ' <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>', ['action' => 'view', $next['id']], ['escape' => false]); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Note:** you are free to use `Cache` or not, but I found it useful in the case you will need this query every time, you can manually refresh the cache key in the `Entity` `afterSave`

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Item $entity, $options)
{
    Cache::delete('items_ids');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ayman. Your solution sounds promising to me. I will try it out in my environment and see how it works. :)

Comment: i am looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: No need for this whole cache thing IMO. All you need is some kind of findNeigbors custom finder which works on the default sorting if not specified otherwise to find the prev and next record. That assumes of course, that there is a clear order on it (e.g. the primary key).

Comment: @AymanAlkom - I tried your solution without cache, but I get internal error. Here is the code: `if (empty($ids)) { $ids = $this->Customers->find('list')->toArray(); } while (key($ids) !== $id) next($ids); prev($ids); $prev = [ 'id' => key($ids), 'name' => current($ids) ]; next($ids); $next = [ 'id' => key($ids),  'name' => current($ids) ]; $cust = $this->Customers->get($id); $this->set(compact(['cust','next','prev'])); $this->set('_serialize', ['cust','next','prev']);` I am curious about this how it turns out.

Comment: @mark - In CakePHP 3.0, there is no find neigbor finder anymore. I think the solution to do such a task is to query a database and get previous and next row by id.

Comment: Hi @Ray, I don't know if the internal error caused by the first or last item case, I will update the answer to treat the case of edges elements

Comment: I tested the code again, and I am using it now in my project.
I also added some debug notes in addition to update the view.ctp to bootstrap.css compatible

Comment: @Ray I noticed your code, you dont have to use !empty($ids) because you dont have $ids yet

Comment: Thanks Ayman for all your affords. I think the problem is with the while loop. I am able to var_dump variable `$ids` which has all the customer ids from customers table. If I understand the while loop correctly if the `key($ids)` doesnt match `$id`, it will load that key in `next($ids)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `foreach` instead of `next and prev`:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $ids = Cache::read('items_ids');
    if (empty($ids)) {
        $ids = $this->Items->find('list')->toArray();
        Cache::write('items_ids', $ids);
    }
    /*
     * $ids here must be something like this:

     Array
        (
            ............
            [GS00001] => Item 1
            [GS00003] => Item 2
            ..........
        )

    */
    //pr($ids);die; //this for debug


    //seek to the item with id = $id
    $found = $next = $prev = false;
    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
        //pr($key);
        if($found){
            $next = [
                'id'   => $key,
                'name' => $value
            ];
            break;
        }
        if ($key == $id) {
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $prev = [
                'id'   => $key,
                'name' => $value
            ];
        }
    }
    //pr(compact(['next','prev']));die;
    /*

    $next and $prev here:

    If first:
    Array
    (
        [next] => false
        [prev] => Array
            (
                [id] => GS00264
                [name] => Last Item
            )

    )

    If last:
    Array
    (
        [next] => Array
            (
                [id] => GS00003
                [name] => First Item
            )

        [prev] => false
    )

     * */


    $item = $this->Items->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['MenuGroups', 'Orders']
    ]);
    $this->set(compact(['item', 'next', 'prev', 'ids']));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['item', 'next', 'prev', 'ids']);
}
```